# Creating method for specific UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this code to embed font to all text field on all UIView :

```
for (UIView *subview in [[self view] subviews]) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)subview;
        [textField setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ABeeZee-Regular" size:14]];
    }
}
```

but, it's just embedding font to text field and it will do to all UIView. on the other hand, I want to create some method to specific UIView, so I decided to add each UIView on my interface file :

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewOne;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewTwo;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewThree;
```

now, how to create for loop to 'select' all UI components (button, label, textfield, etc) on (let's say) UIView viewOne, so that I can create method to it? for example, changing all component alpha = 0?

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
for (UIView *subview in self.viewOne.subviews) {
   if ([subview respondsToSelector:@selector(setAlpha:)])
    subview.alpha = 0;
}
```